# Powershell running command after script

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm new to PowerShell and I'm trying to save few clicks by creating a script for daily tasks (Get Username, Reset Password and Unlock Account).

Here is the issue: When I'm launching my script, Powershell will execute everything except cmdlets and will finish by them.

For instance, when I'm using the first choice (Get username ) it will prompt me the "Press enter to end the script" and then display the result of my GetUserName Function.

Please find my code below :

```
# Author : Maxime
# Creation date :  20/06/2018
# Version : 0.1
Function GetUserName($name)
{
    $u = 'surname -like "' +$name+ '"'
    $res = Get-ADUser -Filter $u | select Name, GivenName, Surname
    return $res
}


echo "Menu"
echo "------"
$choix = read-host " 1. Trouver utilisateur par nom `n 2. Reset Password `n 3. Deverrouiller compte `nChoix  "


if($choix = 1)
{
    $name = Read-Host "Entrez nom utilisateur "
    GetUserName($name)

}
elseif( $choix = 2) 
{
    $id = Read-Host "Entrez ID"
    Set-ADAccountPassword $id -confirm -Reset
}
elseif ($choix -= 3)
{
    $id = Read-Host "Entrez ID "
    Unlock-ADAccount -Confirm $id
}
else
{
    echo "Mauvais choix"
}



read-host "Press enter to end the script ..."
```

Edit:

When I'm launching the script without ISE:

[image]

And when I'm launching the script with the ISE, I can see that my result is displayed after the confirmation to close.

I would like the script to Display the information and then displaying the confirmation to close the window.

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. As far as I see it looks good the code ( I don't have a server to check right now).

Comment: Let met edit and add screenshot :)

Comment: When I test it it'll display output but after you press enter (I'm testing in ISE so I see it). Try to use this (save to variable and pipe to table: `$res = GetUserName($name); $res|ft`

Comment: @robdy, Exactly ! 

Your solution works, do you have any idea why it's displaying after the 'press enter' ?

Comment: Can be something related to [this](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/14925213-bug-console-output-appears-out-of-order). However, I'm glad it works, let me convert it to an answer so you can accept it if you wish.

Comment: @robdy Of course. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that output is displayed before prompt from `Read-Host` you can use:

```
$res = GetUserName($name)
$res | Format-Table
```

Very likely it's related with some delay from `Select-Object` function (also reported [here](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/14925213-bug-console-output-appears-out-of-order)).

Another option is to change this line

```
$res = Get-ADUser -Filter $u | select Name, GivenName, Surname
```

to

```
$res = Get-ADUser -Filter $u | fl Name, GivenName, Surname
```

When you use `Format-List` or `Format-Table` there's no delay and your output is displayed in correct order.